# awk output using printf and color

Tags: bash, awk, terminal, solaris

I am writing a script on an old version of Solaris. Column does not exist. I want to color the second column of a string and format it into basic columns.

Currently I am using

```
off='\033[0m'   
gry='\033[1;90m'
line="test1 test2 test3 test4"
colored=$(echo -e "${gry}1.23${off}")
echo -e "${line}" | awk -F" " '{printf("%-10s%-10s%-10s%s\n", $1,coll,$3,$4)}' coll="${colored}"
```

But when run, the second colored column will have the 3rd column pressed up against it.
Without the color codes the formatting is fine.

I thought this may have to do with zero length chars

```
off='\[\033[0m\]' 
gry='\[\033[1;90m\]'
```

But this just prints the extra brackets.

I want (with colored 2nd column)

```
test1     1.23     test3          test4
test1     1.23     test3          test4
test1     1.23     test3          test4
```

but getting

```
test1     1.23test3          test4
test1     1.23test3          test4
test1     1.23test3          test4
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Just increase the width specifier for the second field. Using 20 seems to look pretty good to me. Those may be zero width on the terminal, but AWK counts them.

Comment: The `\[` and `\]` codes are specific to Bash and only really useful in the Bash prompt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting withing the `printf` receives your ANSI CSI codes and count them in the string parameter width regardless if they are actually printed or not.

since you are *always* coloring the 2nd column, you could move the ANSI CSI sequences within the format string of the `printf` like this:

```sh
line="test1 test2 test3 test4"
colored="1.23"
echo -e "${line}" | awk -F" " '{printf("%-10s\033[1;90m%-10s\033[1;0m%-10s%s\n", $1,coll,$3,$4)}' coll="${colored}"
```